# Commutators in the infinite dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, dihedral-groups

I started to learn about the infinite dihedral group $D_\infty=\langle x,y\mid x^2=y^2=1\rangle.$ Can you tell me some references about this group? I need to know about it as specifically as possible. Now, I'm wondering a few things as follows.

1. $xy$ can be written a product commutator, can't you? Moreover, its commutator can be chosen by elements, which have order $2.$ I hope that $xy$ can be a commutator of elements $c,d$, and $c,d$ have order $2.$
2. How many are elements of order $2$ in $D_\infty$?

Thanks for all your support.

Comment: No, $xy$ is not in the commutator subgroup, so it cannot be written as a product of commutators. The commutator subgroup is the infinite cyclic subgroup $\langle (xy)^2 \rangle$ of index $4$ in $D_\infty$. There are infinitely many elements of order $2$, but they are all conjugates of $x$ or of $y$.

Comment: 1. I think $xy$ is not a commutator. 2. There are infinitely many of them, e.g. $(xy)^nx(xy)^{-n}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Oh, yeah, thank you so much. Can you tell me some references for this group? In particular, I want to know the proof of the commutator subgroup is the infinite cyclic subgroup $\langle (xy)^2\rangle$ of index $4$ in $D_\infty.$

Comment: @Berci Thank you very much.

Comment: I would recommend trying to prove that for yourself rather than looking for references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cosider the group $(G, \circ)$ where:

- $G$ is the set of all functions $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ of the form $f(k) = a \pm k$, $a \in \mathbb{Z}$
- $\circ$ means function composition.

Then $D_{\infty} \cong G$ and via that isomorphism $x$ maps to $x(k) = -k$ and $y$ maps to $y(k) = 1-k$. Since $G$ is a concrete group, it should be easy to answer these questions now.

Comment: On the other hand, the defining presentation shows that $D_\infty \cong C_2*C_2$, which is arguably equally concrete.

Comment: @DerekHolt  The symbol $\ast$ is denoted by free product. Is it right?

Comment: Thank you very much @Adayah.